# XML Parsing Error: junk after document element in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4

I am working with Angular JS and created a simple login form and also implemented routing to route to next page after successful login.

But when I am trying to implement conditional routing, after login I am able to route to next page in my app but the page contents are not being displayed.

### Below shown is my application structure.

[image]

I have created a controller.js file , a login.html and dashboard.html files

`controller.js`:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : "login.html"
    })

    .when('/dashboard', {
        resolve: {
            "check" : function($location, $rootScope) {
                if(!$rootScope.loggedIn) {
                    $location.path('/');
                } else{
                   templateUrl : "dashboard.html" 
                }
            }
        } 
    })

    .otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/'
    });
});

app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope ,$location , $rootScope) {
    $scope.submit = function(){

        if($scope.username == 'asd' && $scope.password == 'asd' ){
            $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
            $location.path('/dashboard');
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Invalid username and password")
        }
    };
});
```

`login.html`:

```html
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-push-4">
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-4">
<div ng-controller="loginCtrl">

<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<h3>Login </h3><hr>
  <form action="/"  id="myLogin">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="username">UserName:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter UserName" ng-model="username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" ng-model="password">
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me</label>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submit()">Login</button>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

`dashboard.html`:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MY APP</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
<br/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="margin: auto;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">

    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

### This is my output window

[image]

can anybody help me in resolving this error...!

Comment: You should be running a local server and not opening a file directly in your browser

Comment: how can i do this..?

Comment: install tomcat / glassfish depending on IDE

Comment: simplest server - [`http-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server). Once installed, go to the path where your root files are located and launch it with `http-server` command. Then instead of opening files in the browser, open `http://localhost:8080/#!/`

Comment: @ShashankVivek .. I am using sublime text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
.when('/dashboard', {
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
    resolve: {
        "check" : function($location, $rootScope) {
            if(!$rootScope.loggedIn) {
                $location.path('/');
            }
        }
    } 
})
```

[Here is the working plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/l0JpoKyIDc1b42LSpErP?p=preview)

Few other points to consider in your code:

1. **use controller name in `config` phase itself rather than writing inside html as `ng-controller`**

Ex:

```
 .when('/', {
    templateUrl : "login.html",
    controller : 'loginCtrl'
 })
```

2. **Remove `action` from `<form>` tag because you are handling via `angularJS` & use `ng-submit`**.

ex:

```
<form id="myLogin" ng-submit="submit()">
```

3. **Remove `$rootScope.loggedIn`, as `rootScope` variables are discouraged, rather use `factories`**

Comment: but still I am getting the same error as shown in the output console in my question....

Comment: @Heena you need local server for that, otherwise it breaks your routing. URLs will looks like `.../index.html/#!/` instead of `/#!/`

Comment: I am using sublime editor and i just opened up my index.html in browser .. but how can i access it through server .. can you please provide me any doc on this or any info how can i accomplish this...?

Comment: @Heena : refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server , is or simplest solution can be is to install netbeans IDE, it has inbuilt server -glassfish ,which will be installed by default.